# Applications of the Gauss-Jordan elimination method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Aware of my minimal knowledge of *linear algebra*, I was seeing the power of the **Gauss-Jordan elimination method**. In particular, it can be used for:

- solve the **linear systems** $A\,X = b$;
- calculate the **rank** of a matrix $A$ $m \times n$;
- calculate the **determinant** of a matrix $A$ $n \times n$;
- calculate the **inverse** of a matrix $A$ $n \times n$ with $\det(A)\ne 0$, considering a matrix $[A \; I]$ which becomes $[I \; A^{-1}]$;
- to **extract a vector base** of the subspace **generated by the column** vectors of a matrix $A$ $m \times n$;
- to **extract a vector base** of the subspace **generated by the kernel** vectors of a matrix $A$ $m \times n$, considering a matrix $[A^t\,I]$ which becomes $[B \; C]$ (excellent method to extract, therefore, also the eigenvectors).

Are there other applications of this method in the field of *linear algebra* besides those listed?

Comment: This is a nice list, but I think one reason your question is not getting answered is that you seem to have asked $3$ separate questions: the title and most of the body talks of applications of Gaussian elimination, the last paragraph asks for tricks that combine the identity matrix in a surprising way, and the last line seems to ask something more general about the whole of linear algebra.